# OdataV3 implementation in Java

Tags: java, odata, olingo, odata4j

I have implemented OdataV4 service using [apache olingo](https://olingo.apache.org/doc/odata4/index.html). I am looking for a library that supports OdataV3 implementation. Clearly, apache olingo doesnt provide libraby for V3 yet. Also tried Odata4J but looks they have declared support for OdataV3 but it was never developed.

Even migration tool which can actually translate oDataV3 request to V4 will also work.